# Android Couchbase - URI for attachments

Tags: android, couchdb, uri, attachment, couchbase

Some of my couchdb attachments are html files. I want to use those html files in the webview. To do this, I need the complete url to the attachment. How do I get the full path to those attachments? Which APIs should I use. I am using Couchbase library for android and Ektorp Client library.

Thanks,
Pramod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.

When the couchdb service is started, the `ICouchBaseDelegate` method `onCouchBaseStarted` is called with `host` and `port` values. This is stored and The url for an attachment `a.html` in a document `doc` inside a couchdb `dbName` is constructed like this :

```
url = "http://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + dbName + "/" + doc + "a.html"
```